# How does Anaconda work with installing packages?

Tags: r, anaconda

I just downloaded anaconda and downloaded their basic R package.

I also got some packages from anaconda, using the anaconda terminal commands that they provide on their website.

My question is -- when I am starting a new R session in r studio, do I still need to install.packages()? Can I just load the package?

When I press libary(rJava) for example -- the R command line doesn't say anything back on whether it was successful, that's why I'm not sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed the R packages via the R command line then you can just directly load them. I would recommend that you use the command line rather than R studio.